# Should 'to be' be involved or it's optional?

Tags: adjectives, adjective-phrases, reduced-relative-clauses

Context:

> *"The nervous system was so complex and highly developed as to leave Lake aghast. Though excessively primitive and archaic in some respects, the thing had a set of ganglial centres and connectives arguing the very extremes of specialised development. Its five-lobed brain was surprisingly advanced; and there were signs of a sensory equipment, served in part through the wiry cilia of the head, involving **factors alien to any other terrestrial organism**."*
>
> ([Source](http://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/texts/fiction/mm.aspx))

I think that 'to be' verb should be involved:

> Factors **ARE** alien to any other terrestrial organism

- *Oxford's elaboration of the definition* ([2.Unfamiliar and disturbing or distasteful](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/alien))

---

Questions:

1. Why didn't the author use 'to be' verb in the sentence?
2. If it's optional- could you please explain these options to me?

Answer (score 2):

It's a participle adjective clause or reduced defining relative clause. Let's have a look on your sentence:

> *"there were signs of a sensory equipment, served in part through the wiry cilia of the head, involving factors alien to any other terrestrial organism."*

In this interesting sentence you see both [adverbial participles](https://www.englishgrammar.org/grammar-terms-adverb-adverb-phrases-adverb-clauses-adverbial-participles/) and [participle adjectives](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/participle-adjectives.html). In details, the adverbial participles are

- "served in part through the wiry cilia of the head"
- "involving factors alien to any other terrestrial organism"

and the adjective participle is

- alien to any other terrestrial organism

---

Now let's get back to your questions.

> 1. Why didn't the author use 'to be' verb in the sentence?

Briefly, they didn't do so because it's wrong. However, the author could say:

> Factors **which(that)** are alien to any other terrestrial organism.

If you do some research on "defining relative clause", you will find that the sentence above can be reduced to

> Factors alien to any other terrestrial organism.

---

> 2. If it's optional- could you please explain these options to me?

Regarding why they preferred to use the adjective participle or reduced relative clause, I would say the reduced version is more eloquent and compact which is preferable, especially in academic or formal texts.

Answer (score 2):

It's an example of a reduced defining relative clause.

- *...and there were signs of a sensory equipment, served in part through the wiry cilia of the head, **involving factors alien to any other terrestrial organism**.*

> A reduced relative clause is a relative clause that is not marked by an explicit relative pronoun or complementizer such as who, which or that.

From [**ThoughtCo**](https://www.thoughtco.com/reduced-relative-clauses-1211107):

> Relative clauses can also be reduced to shorter forms if the relative clause modifies the subject of a sentence. Relative clause reduction refers to removing a relative pronoun to reduce.

Here the subject is "**factors**", And the **relative clause** was reduced to a [**prepositional phrase**](https://www.thoughtco.com/parts-of-a-prepositional-phrase-1689686):

- *...involving factors **that (which) are** alien to any other terrestrial organism.*

To reduce a **relative clause** to a **prepositional phrase** we need to *remove the relative pronoun - (**that/which** in your example)*, *remove the verb 'be' - (**are** in your example)*, and *place the prepositional phrase after the modified noun - ('**factors**' in your example)*.

Here are more examples of defining relative clause reduced to prepositional phrases:

- The box **which was** on the table was made in Italy. > **Reduced**: The box on the table was made in Italy.
- The woman **who was** at the meeting spoke about business in Europe. > **Reduced**: The woman at the meeting spoke about business in Europe.

Comment: @Max This is correct. Another example involving an adjective (to make a more perfect parallel with "alien") might be "She went though a breakup more amicable than the relationship itself had been."